# Restore Time Machine spinning Menu Extra

Tags: time-machine, menu-bar

In Previous version of Mac OS X the Time Machine menu-extra would spin while a backup was in progress.

Since upgrading to Mavericks that has been replaced with a static icon that adds a second arrow when the backup is running. I find it much harder to know when a backup is running. Does anybody know if there any way to restore the pre Mavericks spinning menu-extra behavior in Mavericks?